# How to migrate a root filesystem to another partition from within running system?

Tags: linux, filesystems, rsync

I try to migrate a root filesystem from ext4 to another partition type (zfs) and started with a simple

```
rsync -a --exclude=/boot --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/tmp 
--exclude=[all zfs pools with default mountpoint] 
/ /target/directory/mountpoint/
```

then the transfer got stuck at a different files in `/proc`, after adding `--exclude=/proc` `rsync` got stuck at a file in `/sys/devices`, which lead me to give up trial & error. After reading `man proc` and about `/sys` ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_filesystem#Conventional_directory_layout)) I realize it takes more reasearch than a simple solution requires for me to find it. I hope someone can help. The root system is Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 (the live system as well, but feel free to make suggestions if that is a limiting issue).

Of course it's easy to boot into a live system and copy the data there, but this is a workaround solution for the question only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to start with a disclaimer on this one since I don't have a system I can use to test if booting will actually work. This answer is based on my understanding, and you should only try this on a dev system until you confirm it works.

Since `/dev`, `/sys`, `/proc` are all virtual filesystems, I think the OS should create their contents at boot. If this is true, you should be able to do:

```
rsync -ax / /target/directory/mountpoint
```

The -x tells rsync not to cross filesystem boundaries, so it'll skip virtual filesystems, and no need to specify the zfs pools. It'll still create the mount points, but they'll be empty.

If your /tmp isn't it's own partition, and you don't want to copy those files, you'll still need to manually `--exclude` it.

Comment: That's a good idea! There're still some files vanishing if programs are running (e.g. from `firefox` cache), but that's not part of the question.

Comment: That's very true. You could run through it once to copy the bulk of the files, then run it again to try to catch any changes before you reboot. Some applications will still probably think the computer crashed when it starts back up, but most will handle that well anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you are running LVM.  If so, you can do file system snapshots using LVM and then copy from there.

These were invented because backups need to be created from a quiescent file system or the backup isn't very useful. Snapshots will solve both your cross device issue as well as the transient file issue.

Note that if you have any large files, like databases, which are active, rsync and other backups are likely to produce inconsistent versions as parts of the file will be copied before a database change and others copied after.  Snapshots are an attempt to solve this problem too.

Note: btrfs has a superior form of file system snapshotting, but if you're already running ext4, then it's too late for that this time.

Answer (score 0):

Adjunct: If you can (you can if you are at the local console, you can't if you are connected via ssh or need to keep the system fully running), change to runlevel 1 ("single user mode", the command is "init 1") before doing such a thing. This will stop all non essential processes that could change things in the filesystem while you are copying it.

Mind adjusting your fstab, especially if UUIDs are used.

Consider using "chroot /where/the/new/root/is/mounted /bin/bash" to test your newly replicated filesystem, and possibly to reinstall your boot loader. You may have to manually mount /proc and /sys under the chroot.

If reinstalling a bootloader from chroot, make sure /etc/mtab (in the chrooted system) does not contain garbage that confuses the loader installer. If it is grub 1.x , you might have to delete the (new) /boot/device.map file.

If you want to play it safe with /dev, you can populate it (in the new filesystem) with "MAKEDEV generic" - this will create a set of device files "underneath" the udev mount point that will keep your system from crashing hard at startup in case udev is nonfunctional.